# Concrete understanding of QFT Hilbert space for spinor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, wavefunction, spinors

I'm trying to understand the concepts of a spinor field in QFT.   I naively understand there are two values at each spatial position $\vec{r}$: a probability amplitude and a spinor value.  Is there a probability associated with each orthogonal state of the spinor value?

I came across the [following in an answer to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/560144/32357):

> The actual wave function of an electron (or any other spin $\frac{1}{2}$
> particle for that matter) is the tensor product of (1) and (2) above. $$\begin{pmatrix}\psi_+(\vec{r}) \\ \psi_-(\vec{r})\end{pmatrix} \tag{3}$$ So this function is a member of an $\infty\times 2$-dimensional Hilbert space.
> $\psi_+(\vec{r})$ is the probability-amplitude of the particle being
> at position $\vec{r}$ *and* having spin-up.
> Likewise $\psi_-(\vec{r})$ is the probability-amplitude of the particle being
> at position $\vec{r}$ *and* having spin-down.

Aren't these probability amplitudes are partially related, in that they will together have magnitude one at a position?  So in reality there aren't 4 independent values (2 complex numbers) at each position, right?

When the wave function collapses, can the 4-component spinor value at a position be known?  If so, how should one think of it in terms of the probability amplitude functions specified above?

Answer (score -1):

A 2-dimensional complex vector space attached at each event point space is a 4-dimensional real space. With a complex norm it reduces to a 3d real compact space, So, by the very exposition, its the smallest representation space of the 3d rotation group.

In other words, if one allows for values $\pm 1$ of an operator in quantum theory, by the axioms, that its a representation of self adjoint 2x2-matrix operators with real eigenvalues, one automatically is sitting in the complex 2d- representation of the rotation group, that is

$$SU(2,C) = \exp(\frac{i}{2} \  \vec n . \vec \sigma),\  \forall \vec n \in \mathbb R^3.$$
The total 1-particle representation space is a bundle with a continuous distribution of the 2d Hilbert space without a specific gauge by the choice of the local basis $(1,0), (0,1)$. So, out of nothing, automatically the gauge groups $U(1)\times SU(2,C)$ as representations of translations and rotations in the momentum space basis are part of the game.

All this is a mathematical speciality of 3d-space, where the spin vectors as generators of rotations can be identified with Hamiltons i,j,k- basis vectors of translations.  Made is possible for Maxwell, to detect the 3d nonrelativistic representation of electromagentism.